# Blob constructor

Tags: safari, xmlhttprequest, blob

I am using the below code to open a local text file.It works fine in firefox but in safari i get the error as
**'[object BlobConstructor]' is not a constructor (evaluating 'new Blob([xhr.response])')**.please help me by providing links.

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),blob;
xhr.open('GET', 'example.txt');
xhr.responseType = 'arraybuffer';
xhr.onload = function(e) {
blob = new Blob([xhr.response]);
console.log(blob);


            }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug in the older Safari/WebKits.  Upgrade your browser or operating system.

Note: It still does not appear to accept ArrayBufferView's as arguments, but should be fine for normal arrays.